# Center an element whose width is beyond the viewport

Tags: jquery, css, viewport, centering

I would like to center an element whose width is beyond the viewport (i.e. element = 1000px / viewport = 800px). I already tried basic CSS (margin = 0 auto) but it doesn't work. Would be great if somebody could help me out!

I have three child elements (.project) whose widths are calculated through jQuery. Moreover, the sum of those three child elements are the width of my parent element (#projects).

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufezqsvs/1/).

Cheers

```
$(window).on( "resize", function () {
    var projectWidth = ( $(window).width() / 2.8 );
    $(".project").css({ width : projectWidth.toFixed() });

    var projectSum = 0;
    $("#projects .project").each( function(){ projectSum += $(this).width(); });
    $(".container").css({ width : projectSum });        
}).resize();
```

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333405/css-center-content-thats-wider-than-the-page) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511436/how-can-i-center-align-an-element-that-is-larger-than-100-of-the-entire-page)?

Comment: I read those posts, yes. However, it's a different situation since I am working with dynamic widths.

Comment: not too sure to understand what you want ? : this ? http://jsfiddle.net/ufezqsvs/2/ and then center it ? http://jsfiddle.net/ufezqsvs/3/ if you give up float for display table or inline-block it then much easier and li can have any width.

Comment: what i mean about inline-block and table-cell : http://jsfiddle.net/ufezqsvs/5/ (play with content of lis

Comment: I have a parent element (.container) whose width is wider than the width of the viewport. My goal is to center the parent element within the viewport - means it overlaps the viewport (this isn't visible) on the left and on the right by the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple using CSS. Here is an example where the `body` is set to be `400px` wide and an element of `600px` is aligned in the middle.

The maths is simply `(containerWidth - divWidth) / 2` then use this value as `margin-left` and `margin-right` which you can use with dynamic width from JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/da8y64ww/1/

```
body {
    width:400px;
    border:1px dotted blue;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#foo {
    width:600px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid green;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-right:-100px;
}
```